# The universe ringing like a bell? What would that mean for the cosmological constant?

Tags: cosmology, dark-energy

The claim that the rate of expansion accelerates and decelerates periodically over time is [here](http://phys.org/news/2015-06-universe-crystal-glass.html) and that it has already gone through seven such cycles, each being damped further with each oscillation. What would it mean for the cosmological constant and dark energy - what could cause such oscillations on such a scale?

Comment: Yes - mixup. Fixed now.

Comment: The expansion/contraction dependent on the sign of the constant, the rate on its size, right?

Comment: And specifically how it expands/contracts depends on other elements in the field equations

Comment: What elements in the equations? I asked this because I do not know much cosmology and this is a new research report.

Comment: Sorry - still don't understand what Dark Matter has to do with this

Comment: @Dirk: there is no relation to dark matter and dark energy, outside the word dark in both. Sadly, many non-physicists like to hypothesize they are the same (or at least related).

Comment: While I am not opposed to such models, I seriously doubt that one can successfully explain dark matter observations with them. Dark matter is not just a cosmological problem, it's quite local and a global ringing model can't produce that kind of distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mead and Ringermacher's paper is [available on the Arxiv here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06140). Their previous publication that descibes how they perform their analysis is [also on the Arxiv here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.6300).

Mead and Ringermacher's paper is phenomenological, i.e. it reports an analysis of experimental data (measurements of SN1a red shifts) and the paper suggests a scalar field that could be responsible for the effect. However no attempt is made to link the scalar field to any fundamental theory of physics.

So if I have correctly interpreted Dirk's question as asking what could be the fundamental physics behind the effect then that question has no answer. Any suggestions would be complete speculation. Mead and Ringermacher suggest that the scalar field behaves like dark matter, but it isn't clear whether a dark matter oscillation causes the the field or whether the field causes the apparant presence of dark matter. Again, any comments would just be speculation. Note that the scalar field is unrelated to dark energy and/or the cosmological constant.

I don't know enough about the area to comment on the validity of the analysis and whether the oscillations really exist. Presumably the cosmology community will be examining the work in the next few months and hopefuly some consensus will arise.